# VSCode all autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can VSCode's Intellisense/autocomplete be configured to work across all open files similar to Sublime's All Autocomplete plugin?  Is there an extension that supports this?

Specifically, I am looking to get basic function and variable name autocompletion to work across C, C++, Matlab, and Python source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All actions in VS code are strictly limited to the document, which is passed in to the various APIs an extension has to implement.

I can imagine a hack, however, where you store code completion info persistently (in vscode settings, external file etc.), once you have collected them for a document and use that persistance layer to load all the info from there. This is however not very dynamic and requires that a file has been scanned for code completion info at least once (i.e. it was open in vscode and active at least once).

Comment: This is the conclusion I was coming to, but I was curious if I was missing something.  Thanks for answer.